# How to consolidate different values into numbered column groups

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

If I have a simple dataset, such as follows:

| Name | Subject | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe Bloggs | English | A |
| Joe Bloggs | Maths | B |
| Sam Smith | English | B |
| Sam Smith | Physics | C |

Is there a way to create column groupings so that the data displays as follows:

| Name | Subject 1 | Grade 1 | Subject 2 | Grade 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe Bloggs | English | A | Maths | B |
| Sam Smith | English | B | Physics | C |

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried various ways with nested tables, etc but the fact that you can't use aggregate functions in filters scuppers that approach.

Comment: Use a Matrix instead. You'll just need to add some kind of row number to your data so that you have a value for your column groupings.

Comment: @ThomA Thanks for the quick reply - I was hoping there would be a neat way to do it purely on the report side but it looks like I will need to do the counting in the query instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thom A suggested, you'll need to add a column to handle your row groups but it's simple enough.

Here's I've created some sample data and added an extra row so you can see it working when the number of subjects varies between Names.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Name varchar(20), Subject varchar(20), Grade varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES 
('Joe Bloggs', 'English', 'A'),
('Joe Bloggs', 'Maths', 'B'),
('Sam Smith', 'English', 'B'),
('Sam Smith', 'Physics', 'C'),
('Sam Smith', 'T-SQL', 'C')


SELECT 
    *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY Subject) AS ColN
    FROM @t
```

This gives us the following results

[image]

In your report, add a Matrix and drop `Name` into the Row placeholder and `ColN` into the column placeholder.

Right click the column header (`[ColN]`) and do "insert column Inside Group Right". Now just drop you subject and grade fields into the two columns.

You can refine the column header but I just left it as-is here. Here's the result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alan, that's really helpful - the unfortunate thing is that SSRS doesn't allow you to use certain things (such as OVER) in its SQL queries. I suppose I could create a view then use that instead, it's just frustrating though that SSRS doesn't provide a way to handle this on the report design side.

Comment: That's not true. You can put whatever you like in a dataset query. I have entire scripts 100s of lines long sometimes. The **designer** can't handle that but if you simply double-click the dataset name and choose text as the query type, you can do what you like. I never use the query designer as I find it creates horrible code that's not easy to read.

Comment: Oh, and if this does solve your problem, please mark the question as accepted (the check mark to the left below the vote up/down buttons). This helps other users find answered questions when looking for something similar.

Comment: I'm an idiot! I've fallen into the habit of using the designer and never thought to try it just in the text view! That works a treat and saves me having a load of sql views that I don't need. Thanks Alan.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I'm an avid avoider of Wizards and designers, :)